# Cannot access CSS in /static/ with url_for('static', filename='...') in Flask

Tags: python, flask

so I'm kinda stumped on this one.

Currently, my flask app is structured like this:

```
/project_dir/
    /app/
        __init__.py
        /templates/
            base.html
        /static/
            /css/
                main.css
            /js/
                main.js
        routes.py
    /other_code/
        a.py
        b.py
        c.py
    run.py
```

Now, when I try to do this in base.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
```

I don't get the css linked to the page.

However, when I move the static folder up one-level into /project_dir/, it works.

How can I configure flask to get the static folder from inside of the app folder?

Inspecting the source of the rendered base.html, the path to the css is generated as this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css">
```

Clicking on that href will jsut bring you to a Flask 404.

run.py:

```
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__'
app.run(debug=False)
```

app/_ *init* _.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask('My App', template_folder='app/templates')

from app import routes
```

Comment: Are you getting `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound`? `templates` and `static` folder should be at project root folder.

Comment: How do you instantiate `Flask` app?

Comment: Please show how you are instantiating flask app?

Comment: I added the source of run.py and app/init.py to my post. The top-level run.py just starts the app variable from init.py.